# Vandermonde-like matrix and its determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I meet the following matrix.

$$\left[\begin{array}{lllll}
1 & x_1^{d} & x_2^{d} & \cdots & x_{d}^{d} \\
1 & x_1^{d-1} & x_2^{d-1} & \cdots & x_d^{d-1} \\
1 & x_1^{d-2} & x_2^{d-2} & \cdots & x_d^{d-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & x_1^0 & x_2^0 & \cdots & x_d^0
\end{array}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{(d+1) \times (d+1)}.$$

At first glance, it looks like the Vandermonde matrix. Suppose $x_i \neq x_j$ for any $i \neq j$, is this matrix nonsingular or can we compute its determinant?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

This matrix can be obtained from the Vandermonde matrix in $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_d$ by

- transposing;
- permuting columns;
- setting $x_0=1$.

The first two operations do not change the determinant, except for a possible change of sign.  So the matrix is invertible if and only if the original Vandermonde is invertible.  This will be the case if no two of the $x_k$ are equal - that is, including both your $x_1,\ldots,x_d$ and the newly introduced $x_0=1$.